# Why isn't my implementation of A2C for the the atari pong game converging?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pytorch, actor-critic-methods, convergence

I have two different implementations with PyTorch of the Atari Pong game using A2C algorithm. Both implementations are similar, but some portion are different.

1. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12YQO4r9v7aFSMqE47Vxl_4ku-c4We3B2?usp=sharing

The above code is from the following Github repository: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/blob/master/Chapter10/02_pong_a2c.py It converged perfectly well!

You can find an explanation in Maxim Lapan's book *Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-on* page 269

Here is the mean reward curve :

[image]

2. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jkZtk_-kR1Mls9WMbX6l_p1bckph8x1c?usp=sharing

The above implementation has been created by me based on the Maxim Lapan's book. However, the code is not converging. There's a small portion of my code that is wrong, but I can't point out what it is. I've been working on that near a week now.

Here is the mean reward curve :

[image]

Can someone tell me the problem portion of the code and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE 1**

I have decided to test my code with a simpler environment, i.e. `Cartpole-v0`.

Here is the code : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zL2sy628-J4V1a_NSW2W6MpYinYJSyyZ?usp=sharing

Even that code doesn't seem to converge. Still can't see where is my problem.

**UPDATE 2**

I think the bug might be in the [ExperienceSource](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FJeremieGauthier%2FAI_Exercices%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FAtari_Breakout%2FBreakout_A2C%2Fexperience.py%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR1wP3QhgYQ7Bd2rtYcTTzi5Ne0o9cJuxTJAOyTXhYXReDQq9JVAUCR6pyM&h=AT1CW-RwYDgt1g5EmMSgcNUwdjqxy9yDYkUMaBihpuL9dnAEJGkOWfwIQSdLoQYtqlCWo4PFWEDol8oLVu67oD2TWLqbn9EChoE_Sx5-7Aw5OnFj58Z5eKno1mpk7g) class or in the [Agent](https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FJeremieGauthier%2FAI_Exercices%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FAtari_Breakout%2FBreakout_A2C%2Fagent.py%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR0RsFusMNhK0Qo2H4bE0_Szlu4rVU7imhsh1m3WYbb531pnc_xe2VCpFvY&h=AT1CW-RwYDgt1g5EmMSgcNUwdjqxy9yDYkUMaBihpuL9dnAEJGkOWfwIQSdLoQYtqlCWo4PFWEDol8oLVu67oD2TWLqbn9EChoE_Sx5-7Aw5OnFj58Z5eKno1mpk7g) class.

**UPDATE 3**

The following [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/21073/once-the-environments-are-vectorized-how-do-i-have-to-gather-immediate-experien?noredirect=1#comment32363_21073) will help you understand the classes `ExperienceSource` and `ExperienceSourceFirstLast`.

Comment: Note that programming issues are off-topic here. This issue is in the context of RL, so I may not close it.

Comment: Thanks @nbro! I will keep that in mind. As you allow me, I will leave my question active. Otherwise, I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/JeremieGauthier/AI_Exercices/commit/5a54cbcb53887321b272f0a37d149d3d9c3f7304)

I fixed few minor errors, but the major one was when I saw what the line `histories = [deque(maxlen=self.reward_steps)] * len(self.env.envs)` was doing. It was just repeating the same queue.

```
In [2]: histories = [deque(maxlen=5)] * 4                                       

In [3]: histories                                                               
Out[3]: [deque([]), deque([]), deque([]), deque([])]

In [4]: histories[0].append(1)                                                  

In [5]: histories                                                               
Out[5]: [deque([1]), deque([1]), deque([1]), deque([1])]
```

So I just replace it by `histories = [deque(maxlen=self.reward_steps) for i in range(len(self.env.envs))]`. That fixed my problem.

```
In [7]: histories = [deque(maxlen=5) for i in range(4)]                         

In [8]: histories                                                               
Out[8]: [deque([]), deque([]), deque([]), deque([])]

In [9]: histories[0].append(1)                                                  

In [10]: histories                                                              
Out[10]: [deque([1]), deque([]), deque([]), deque([])]
```

The curve representing the mean reward looks like

[image]